# unable to pass cmd command as TCHAR

Tags: c++

I am working on Visual Studio C++. I want to pass cmd command to an executable file path to type TCHAR in my code.  I was able to successfully run in command line. When I try to tweak in my code, it doesn't takes whole path.Can anyone give ideas how to make this path work.

```
TCHAR cmd[]  = _T(""C:\"Program Files (x86)\ABC MCC 7500"\bin\DebugMonitor.exe runQuery --host_client "EXY DISPATCH" --query 1"");
```

Thank you

Comment: Start by escaping your embedded double-quotes and backslashes as needed in your literal string.

Comment: I need to remove the double quotes? I have used to escape the folder spaces.

Answer (score 1):

escape any special charecter for quotes(") use \" and \ for a backslash () 
try this:

```
TCHAR cmd[]  = _T("\"C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\\ABC MCC 7500\"\\bin\\DebugMonitor.exe runQuery --host_client \"EXY DISPATCH\" --query 1\"");
```

Comment: Thank you. Application is fine, it takes entire path now but when I tried to use this in command line , it throws an error saying : 
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: What are you using to send commands to command line?
Try printing cmd variable in the screen check to see if path displayed is correct one.

Comment: Yes second      \" needs to be removed to get correct results Thanks a lot @marcini

Comment: I am not passing any commands to cmd, Manually am checking in command line whether the path works or not .
You mean to say this way:
TCHAR cmd[]  = _T("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABC MCC 7500\\bin\\DebugMonitor.exe runQuery --host_client \"EXY DISPATCH\" --query 1\"");

Comment: Yes i mean that. And if you want you can directly send that command to windows command line with system() of stdlib.h just be sure to use char data type as its argument not TCHAR

Comment: TCHAR cmd[]  = _T("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABC MCC 7500\\bin\\DebugMonitor.exe\" runQuery --host_client \"EXY DISPATCH\" --query 1"); This worked for me. Thanks